# Can I store subscriptions in a collection named differently than on server

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to store subscriptions of the same server collection in a different minimongo collection?

If not is there any best practice to work around?

I do have a summary table having 50k datasets with a lot of details in the documents.

```
// Server
var collection = new Meteor.Collection("collection");
Meteor.publish("detail", function (id) {
   return collection.find({_id: id});
});
// A pager that does not include the data (fields:{data:0})
Meteor.publish("master", function (filter, sort, skip, limit) {
   return collection.find({name: new RegExp("^" + filter + "|\\s" + filter, "i")},
                          {limit: limit, 
                           skip: skip, 
                           sort: options, 
                           fields: {data: 0}
                          });
});

// Client
var collection = new Meteor.Collection("collection");
Deps.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe("master",
      Session.get("search"),
      Session.get("sort"),
      Session.get("skip"),
      Session.get("limit")
  );
  Meteor.subscribe("detail", Session.get("selection"));
});
```

Problem above: both subscriptions are feed into the same collection.

This does not work well if the results of the finds are stored in the same local collection.

Having a local collection with the name of the subscription/publish would be great.

```
// Client
var detail = new Meteor.Collection("detail"),
   master = new Meteor.Collection("master");
```

Any Ideas how to encourage subscriptions to use my own collections??

Comment: The **Discover Meteor** book discusses this in detail in chapter 13.5. I would consider checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution through help of Andrews Hint the **Discover Meteor** book that shows a lot of publishing subscription scenarios.

Anyway: After reading I discovered that the question I was heading for is also answered in the Meteor documentation [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)

The last example basically creates a virtual collection "counts" for the "messages" collection. Well done already ;-)

"Wer lesen kann ist im Vorteil!"